# How to find n nearest neighbors using a built-in function in R

Tags: r, knn

I have a dataset with a following structure:

```
Number of Rows = 1000
```

Each row corresponds to an article

```
Number of Columns = 502

Column 1 : Title of the article
Column 2 : Text of the article
From column  3 to column 502 : Each column corresponds to a unique word appearing in the corpus of all the articles in the data set and gives the count of this word in the article
```

Given the title of a single article from the above dataset the problem is to find 10 articles closest to it in terms of content using k-nearest neighbor algorithm.
I can implement this algorithm from scratch but I want to use a built-in function in R.
 R documentation for knn https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/class/html/knn.html seems to be for supervised learning 
Please explain how to use this for this case which is actually a case of unsupervised learning

Comment: Do you mean [`stats::kmeans`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kmeans.html)?

Comment: k-NN is a supervised learning algorithm, and this doesn't look like a supervised learning problem to me.  It seems you are trying to cluster the articles based on the words.  If you are looking for the 10 closest articles, you could look at the distance between the vectors.  Does this sound more like what you are looking for?

Comment: @smanski. Exactly. I can implement a code to calculate distance between vectors, but I was looking for some built-in function in R which can straightaway give me the 10 nearest neighbors

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the tip. I will explore stats:kmeans